# Limit of $x^\frac{1}{x}$ as x approaches $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

At calculus - an intuitive and physical approach(2nd) 410p

> 1. Evaluate the following limits:
>    ...
>    (j) $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\,x^\frac{1}{x}$
>    ...

My attempt: $y = \frac{1}{x}$ is not continuous at $x = 0$. So I have to find out $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\,x^\frac{1}{x}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}\,x^\frac{1}{x}$.
i) $y = \lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\,x^\frac{1}{x} \iff \log y = \lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\,\left(\frac{1}{x}·\log x\right) = \infty·-\infty = -\infty \iff y = e^{-\infty} = 0$. 
So $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\,x^\frac{1}{x} = 0$.
ii) $y = \lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}\,x^\frac{1}{x} \iff \log y = \lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} \left(\frac{1}{x}·\log x\right)$. I couldn't go farther because $\log x$ is not defined where $x<0$.
The solutions to this exercise is written as

> (j) Let $y = x^{\frac{1}{x}}$. Then $\log y = \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\log x$. Now $\frac{1}{x}$ becomes infinite and $\log x$ becomes infinite. Hence $\log y$ and so $y$ becomes infinite.

I don't understand this because as I said I think $\log x$ becomes minus infinite(not infinite) when $x$ approaches $0^+$ and even $\log x$ is not defined where $x$ approaches $0^-$. What was wrong with my thought?

Comment: There is a problem with the definition of $x^{1/x}$ for $x<0$. (It is multi-valued if you use complex numbers). I think you are supposed to take the right hand limit.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I agree with that. My book says "There are logarithms for negative and even complex numbers, but they are not considered in elementary calculus". But my conclusion to $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\,x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is $0$ but solution suggests $\infty$ even if the right hand limit is supposed.

Comment: The solution suggests that the limit is $e^{-\infty}=0$ but it is not worded properly.

Comment: Evaluate right hand limit at $x=0$ i.e., $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$ and which is exists.

Comment: The correct question is is to find  $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{\frac{1}{x}}$